# How do I index my output into a length(x)x2 matrix?

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, calculus

I have a script which given two values around my critical point outputs the 
x and y values for said critical point.

I have a x-vector with all my guesses for x and a y-vector with all my guesses for y.

Now I want to take the first elements from each vector. Put it into my

function

```
[x,y]=MyMinMax(f,a,b)
```

and give me my two correct values for x & y.

I now want to place these values in a Nx2 matrix.

Where all the  x's are in the first column and all the y's are in the second column.

You can see my current iteration of the code.

```
f=@(x,y)topography(x,y);

x=[3.44 1.4 2.1 3.278 3.15 5.217 6.054 ...
    5.385 5.786 5.953 6.89 6.455 7.86 9.13 9.298 9.565];
y=[2.94 9.06 8.094 9.331 8.528 9.097 6.488 ...
    5.117 4.08 3.378 1.204 8.595 3,177 5.452 6.355 8.763];
a=zeros(length(x));
b=zeros(length(y));


for i=1:length(x)

[a,b]=MyMinMax(f,x(i),y(i))


end
```

What I expect is to have Nx2 matrix such that all the x values are in the first column with its matching y in the second column.

Something like:

```
x(1) | y(1)
-----------
x(2) | y(2)
-----------
x(3) | y(3)
-----------
x(4) | y(4)    

...
```

and so on.

If what I try to convey is unintelligible, let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Did you try indexing into the output array? It helps if you show what you tried and why it doesn’t do what you wanted.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have tried indexing my output like [a(i),b(i)]=MyMinMax(f,x(i),y(i)

But when printing it, it gives me some weird answer clustered with zeros and my x & y values inbetween. I don't really know how to interpret  the result

Comment: Maybe `MyMinMax` is giving you zero outputs? try initialise `a` and `b` with `nan`.

Comment: @Anthony Now I get the same output with NaN instead of 0's :)

Comment: use`nan(size(x))`. Oh and you have a mistake here. If you only supply `zeros()` or `nan()` with one argument, it will produce a square matrix and probably that is why you have a bunch of zeros. Check the examples [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html#btovuwl-4)

Comment: So sometimes your function doesn’t produce an output?

Comment: @CrisLuengo no, there's always an output. Not as structured I would like to have though